# iOS - Tab bar UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an app with tab bar, having three different tabs. On the second tab I want to hide some controls (textfields & labels) when each tab lost its focus i.e. when user goes to another tab.
Is there any specific method to do so.
By the way, I know the code for hiding controls.

```
[anylbl setHidden:YES];
```

I just want to know methods for view lost focus.

Comment: go through tabbar delegate methods like - shouldSelectViewController or didSelectViewController

Comment: Use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1; to lost focus on other tabs.I don't know this helps you or not..

Comment: @Vidhyanand: This will help. Thnx!

Comment: @Nayan: As **Balram Tiwari** illustrates in answer. This is also a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For firing events when closing the view you can use:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _yourLabel.hidden = YES;
    _yourImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

You can also use:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    _yourLabel.hidden = YES;
    _yourImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to. Bt it was giving me error of short time. (:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to respond to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, then you have these methods.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

This way you can control this on a controller level rather than a viewAppearance level.